# How can I get rails parameters to accept an array of strings?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, parameters

I have a model which has an array of strings.

```
class A < ApplicationRecord
  serialize :vals, Array
end
```

How can I get my controller

```
class AController < ApplicationController
  def create
    par = params.require(:a).permit(:vals)
    ...
  end
end
```

to accept an array of inputs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try declaring it as an array of values:

```
def create
  par = params.require(:a).permit(vals: [])
  ...
end
```

Comment: rails does not like this if I have more than one parameter e.g. params.require(:a).permit(:b,vals:[])

Comment: How's it? Rails doesn't like it?

Comment: Apparently, this only happens if you put vals:[] in the middle of two parameters.

Comment: Yes, you're right, it must be added as the last value, not the first one, nor in the middle, although can be if it's the only one.